# How do I configure Gmail to collapse inbox sections by default when using Multiple Inboxes?

Tags: gmail

I use Gmails Multiple Inboxes setting in which I have set up 3 Inbox sections (which are all work related) as follows:
[image: multiple inbox sections settings]

All inbox sections have some e-mails in them which are all visible when I open my Gmail Inbox.

Since they're all work related inboxes I would like to be able to collapse these Inboxes in my evenings and weekends and have them stay collapsed after a page refresh but unfortunately they're open again after a page refresh.

Is there a way to configure that the Inbox sections should be collapsed by default or that they remember the last open / closed state?